# How to run an ansible task if ufw is enabled?

Tags: ansible, ufw

I need to run some tasks only if ufw is enabled on the Ubuntu server.

Pseudocode looks like:

```
 - name: detect if ufw is enabled
   magical_module: ???
   register: ufw_is_enabled

 - name: my task
   when: ufw_is_enabled
```

I see only this nonelegant solution:

- exec remotely `ufs status`
- parse the output:

```
root@test:~# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Maybe there is some file when ufw is enabled? In this case, it will be possible to use `stat` module. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```yaml
    - name: check whether ufw status is active
      shell: ufw status
      changed_when: false
      register: ufw_check

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ufw_check }}"

    - name: do something if ufw is enabled
      shell: echo
      when: "'inactive' not in ufw_check.stdout"
```

Make sure to use `become: true`, since root privileges are required to successfully execute the command.

To manage systems with the UFW module, [see this Ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ufw_module.html)

What you can do, for example is, disable UFW on systems on which you want it disabled:

```yaml
    - name: Disable UFW on hosts
      ufw:
        state: disabled # unloads firewall and disables firewall on boot.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `check_mode` of the UFW module is a better way to do this. Using the command module is generally not recommended.

```yaml
- name: Check wether enabling UFW would be considered a changed
  check_mode: true
    community.general.ufw:
      state: enabled
    register: ufw_enable_check 

- name: Is UFW enabled?
  debug:
    msg: "{{ not ufw_enable_check.changed }}"
```

`check_mode` will predict whether something will be a change of the current configuration. The UFW module supports this for any parameter. If enabling UFW would be a configuration change, you can assert that UFW is currently not enabled.